# use $inlinecount without MapODataServiceRoute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

i have a **controller 1** inherited form ApiController returning IQueryable of some entity.

i have another **controller 2** returning same thing but inherited form ODataController and oData route configurations like this

```
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<StoreCommand>("StoreCommandsTest");
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "OData", routePrefix: "api", model: builder.GetEdmModel());
        config.AddODataQueryFilter();
```

when i try to run http://localhost:xxxx/api/Controller1?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=0     i get blank json object result

when i try to run http://localhost:xxxx/api/Controller2?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=0     i get proper results with odata.count = 100

my question is what is wrong in the case of controller 1 ?

eventually i am trying to get just **only the count**.

Answer (score 0):

Those query options should work with ApiController, but you should add `EnableQuery` attribute in controller's method.

http://localhost:xxxx/api/Customers/$count to get just only the count.